# Unresolved external symbol CompleteAuthToken referenced

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, sspi

While porting a desktop application to windows mobile I've reached the following error:

> Error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol CompleteAuthToken referenced in
>   function

Reading MSDN it tell me that CompleteAuthToken is supported on Windows CE 2.10 and later and I should link against Secur32.lib, but adding that library didn't fix the unresolved symbol error. Any ideas?

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 + Windows Mobile 6.0 SDK.

Comment: added it to both debug and release configurations and tried a complete rebuild? (sorry for this trivial question, but who knows :))

Comment: yes I've done that, also looking at secur32.lib with dumpbin reveal that such symbol is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the MSDN docs are wrong. Looking in the Platform Builder source, I see that CompleteAuthToken() is in schannel.def and that it gets built into schannel.lib, not secure32.lib.  See if making that change helps.

Comment: I've tried with schannel.lib, but this library is missing from Windows Mobile SDK 6.0 (it is also missing from 5.0).

Comment: Thank you for the hint about "schannel.dll". CompleteAuthToken() is actually exported by that library, and I could load it dynamically via GetProcAddress(). Note that this whole problem is resolved in Windows CE 7.0.

Answer (score -1):

Did you include Security.h?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374764(VS.85).aspx

Comment: unresolved externals mean a missing definition (forgot to include a library to didn't give a function a body, stuff like that). headers primarily provide declarations not definitions.